# VPN issue in Ubuntu

Tags: vpn

I have a situation few days now, where one of our remote users has strange issue with his VPN connectivity to our second VPN server (Cisco ASA). There isn't issue on the ASA configuration, because all works fine for any other users, from different locations. Even I tried with his profile from different machines and all is well. 
The issue is that he is able to establish the tunnel, but not able to access the local resources. Even though he has ping connectivity to the servers. Testing the ports from his machines using telnet was also successful. Not able to access the WEB and SSH no mater I'm using IP or FQDN. I'm not sure where to look now. The route table looks fine. Give me some advice how to investigate this. I've noticed that he has a junk nameserver IP in /etc/resolve.conf 127.0.0.53. And also after established VPN connection, the internal DNS IPs are not populated in resolve.conf. I need your help guys. Thanks!

Outputs:

```
ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mar 27 08:03 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

cat /etc/resolve.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search asatnet.net


$ sudo systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 19 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.xx.xx
                      192.168.xx.xx
          DNS Domain: <domain>

Link 5 (ppp0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
```

I also tested 443 and 22 to our local server with tcpdump/ telnet and it seems to be listening and it has access to the remote ports:

```
 $ telnet xxx.domain.xxx 443
Trying 192.168.yy.yyy...
Connected to xxx.domain.xxx
Escape character is '^]'.



^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.



$ sudo tcpdump -nnn -i tun0 dst port 443
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
17:58:08.124308 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.37600 > 192.168.yy.yyy.443: Flags [P.], seq 1839497978:1839497980, ack 4013729976, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566817412 ecr 3737518068], length 2
17:58:12.448693 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.37600 > 192.168.yy.yyy.443: Flags [P.], seq 2:4, ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566821736 ecr 3737533137], length 2
17:58:13.742958 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.37600 > 192.168.yy.yyy.443: Flags [P.], seq 4:6, ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566823031 ecr 3737537467], length 2
17:58:22.070210 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.37600 > 192.168.yy.yyy.443: Flags [F.], seq 6, ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566831358 ecr 3737538757], length 0
17:58:22.205701 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.37600 > 192.168.yy.yyy.443: Flags [.], ack 2, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566831493 ecr 3737547086], length 0
^C
5 packets captured
5 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel


$ telnet 192.168.yy.yyy 22
Trying 192.168.yy.yyy...
Connected to 192.168.yy.yyy.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4

Protocol mismatch.
Connection closed by foreign host.

~$ sudo tcpdump -nnn -i tun0 dst port 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
17:59:03.479558 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [S], seq 655161819, win 27440, options [mss 1372,sackOK,TS val 2566872767 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:59:03.612253 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [.], ack 3463176096, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566872900 ecr 4260145591], length 0
17:59:03.759173 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [.], ack 42, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566873047 ecr 4260145734], length 0
17:59:06.453527 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [P.], seq 0:2, ack 42, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566875741 ecr 4260145734], length 2
17:59:06.586761 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [.], ack 61, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566875875 ecr 4260148565], length 0
17:59:06.587035 IP 192.168.xx.xxx.47946 > 192.168.yy.yyy.22: Flags [F.], seq 2, ack 62, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 2566875875 ecr 4260148565], length 0
```

No issues with external domains web access.

Comment: Without VPN up, try `ping 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com` and lets make sure that basic DNS is working. 127.0.0.53 is not a junk nameserver, its the local DNS resolver systemd-resolve. Then bring up VPN and retry the first two commands, and also `systemd-resolve  --status` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Edit your question with all of the results.

Comment: I had this issue I remember I put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` into `/etc/resolv.conf` and it worked, just disconnect and connect the internet or reboot if it won't work. It happend to me after kernel upgrade

Comment: it will rewrite `resolv.conf` next time you reboot

Comment: @JoKeR Don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf. Says so right in the file. Fix the real problem instead.

Comment: I agree but it rewrites itself after the reboot anyways. In my case it helped to debug it. Probably VPN glitch it happend only once when I upgraded kernel.

Comment: I'm going to connect remotely to the user's machine I try to investigate again, but please note that he has no issue when is VPN connected to the other firewall's VPN. There all works as expected. From other point of view I have no such of issue from other machines connected to either VPN.